# where does the MBEAN server store all the metrics?

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I am new to JMX. I heard that MBEAN's write to MBEAN server locally. And I am wondering where does the MBEAN server store all the metrics? what happens when the MBEAN server crashes? all the metrics are lost?

Answer (score 0):

The MBean server is just a component of your application. A regular Java object implementing the [`MBeanServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html) interface.

Most metrics MBeans are probably just storing their data in memory, like most Java objects.

Yes, the data will be lost if the server/application/JVM crashes, just like all other in-memory data, unless you have something else reading it out and storing it somewhere else.

Comment: MBean server and say my application are two different JVM's or one JVM?

Comment: @user1870400 It's part of your application therefore must be in the same JVM. It's called an MBean *server* because it serves MBeans; it's not some completely separate process.